# Can't find the go-pear.bat file PHP 5.5 Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, pear

The command from their documentation says to run the command:

```
C:\php>php go-pear.phar
Could not open input file: go-pear.phar
```

According to [Installation Documents](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) the `go-pear.bat` file should be located in the root of the php files `(c:\php)`. I have downloaded [php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x64.zip) to go with my `x64` version of `Apache 2.4`

The closest thing I have to this is: phar.phar.bat.

When trying to run this I get the following:

```
C:\php>"C:\php\php.exe" "C:\php\pharcommand.phar"
No command given, check C:\php\pharcommand.phar help
```

or

```
C:\php>php phar.phar.bat
"%~dp0php.exe" "%~dp0pharcommand.phar" %*
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a system-wide search for "php.exe"?

Comment: yep, php is there. its working perfectly. `PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2014 11:04:07)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you save go-pear.phar to C:\php\ ? If php is working fine then you should be able to just cd to the directory where you saved the go-pear.phar file and do

```
 $ php go-pear.phar
```

Comment: You need to download it from the website as per the line: "To update your PEAR installation, request http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar in your browser and save the output to a local file go-pear.phar. You can then run

php go-pear.phar"

Comment: Fantastic news :) and overlooked by myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries - would it have helped if that line was more prominent in that documentation on the PEAR site? I have edit rights ;)

Comment: ha, it sure would. I think the fact it was the last line and didn't seem to important kind of made me lazy and I stopped reading. Maybe a pretty box around it? Just getting up and running with MDB2... My next task is finding where the `MDB2.php` is that is used in all of the documentation notes ;)

Comment: How I missed that `MDB2.php` is in the root of pear does blow my mind a little bit I admit. I went straight for the `MDB2` folder in my defense.

Comment: That's the way those packages and files in them are usually structured - if you see a FOO folder in the root directory, you should also see a FOO.php file there too, as a general rule of thumb.

Comment: I've always been a fan of writing my own code from scratch. Seemly too long in coding has made me look for out of the box packages, to actually get where I want to me in my projects. Thanks for your help. You know when googling brings up nothing that you are normally the edge case :)

Comment: Heh, I tend to look for at least components of what I can "wire" together for what I need first before I write my own - so long as they're compatible license-wise ;) That's how/why I got involved with PEAR.

Comment: Amazing, just had the same problem again :) Google it, my question

Answer (score 0):

if you can't find the go-pear.bat file, try with the go-pear.phar
you must to download it on the PEAR website. after that, place it in this folder according your apache server configuration "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12"